# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - IdentityUser Issue - Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have upgraded my code from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to Core 2.1. I created a new Core 2.1 project and moved my code into the new project. I have provided samples of my startup and `ApplicationDbContext`

I get the following error when trying to Log In

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not
>   included in the model for the context.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.get_EntityType()

startup.cs

```
//Core 2.1
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();            

////Old Core 2.0 Code
  //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : 
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
 options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
     }
 }
```

I have reviewed the following Microsoft articles :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/30/asp-net-core-2-1-0-now-available/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try changing `public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` to `public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`

Compiler will generate [DbSet](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/EF/IdentityUserContext.cs#L82) with the type provided to generic `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` class.

Comment: h@ly$h1t! this was the answer! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 24):

From Your startup.cs change

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
```

To

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
```

Comment: But this overides any custom fiels on login

Answer (score 7):

As a follow up: to avoid the next possible issue as soon as this here is fixed: You also have to change the types in the `Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml`

From

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

To

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the `ApplicationDbContext` to:

```
private static bool _Created = false;

public ApplicationDbContext()
{
    if (!_Created)
    {
        _Created = true;
        Database.EnsureCreated();

    }
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"server = .\SQLSERVER; initial catalog = DBName; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; App = EntityFramework & quot; ");
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```