# AddIdentity() fails "InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application"

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to add facebook login to my .NET Core 2.1 site

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1) , guide and more specific, [this (for facebook login)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

After have adding the lines below to startup.cs, inside ConfigureServices-method

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    ...
}
```

I get the error message, when I'm running the application. Without these lines it works "ok".  The user can login to facebook and approve my application and I get email and what not. BUT I'm guessing the user information will not be added to my database

> **InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application**
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(string
> name, Action configureBuilder)...

The code goes past the added lines and the error appears after a short while (during startup). I have searched in my project (which is just a bare .NET Core 2.1 Web application, from template) and I cant see any other usages of "AddIdentity".

I did find a "AddDEfaultIdentity()", commented that line out. but then I got

> **InvalidOperationException: No service for type**
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
> has been registered. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I had a similar issue. This might be more helpful for people using .Net Core 3.0. After digging around I found out that once you create an "Identity" area using scaffolding. A file called "IdentityHostingStartup.cs" is created inside the Identity folder.

[image: IdentityHostingStartup Location]

Inside the class, another instance of "AddDefaultIdentity" is created along with a few other services.

[image: IdentityHostingStartup File View]

If you remove the "addDefaultIdentity" from your "Startup.cs" your app should start. Also, If you are getting a null connection string error. Update the connection string inside of the IdentityHostintgStartup.cs

Note: Deleting either of the addDefaultIdentities will work. You just can't have it in both locations.

Comment: If you are using .Net Core 3.0 This is the solution.

Comment: This is the real solution

Comment: I just LOL'd after reading the answer... I was really expecting the scaffolder to update the startup somehow, but the class was left unchanged... The principle of least surprise is completely out of the window.

Comment: Don't forget to check, that you use same identity model if you scaffolded from existing Identity where usualy ApplicationUser is derived from IdentityUser.

Comment: in .Net Core 5.0 
You Should delete this part
" services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser> " from the StartUp

Answer (score 20):

I also had the same problem.

I found out that `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()` had been added when scaffolding Identity, so it was now in 2 places in Program.cs/StartUp.cs (depending on which version of .net core you are using.)

I removed one of them and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

Under .Net 6, go to program.cs and comment duplicated connectionString, AddDbContext and AddDefaultIdentity:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' not found.");

//builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
//    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));;

//builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();;

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: In my case not exactly a duplication but same effect. .NET 8 - The scaffolding was adding back "builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<..>" while I had replaced it with "builder.Services.AddIdentity<...>" at some point.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, with my plugin Kestrel web server project.
I have a plugin using Microsoft Identity, and when I use that plugin two times, I get the `"InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application"` exception.

As mentioned earlier in this thread, the error comes from calling "services.AddIdentity" more then one time. In my project once for each time the plugin is used.

Anyway the solution was to replace:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>((options) => { ... })....
```

With:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>((options) => { ... })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()....
```

The latter apparently catches the exception.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I am using .NET 5 on Debian 10.

Comment: This problem also have in blazor web server global 8.0.0. & 8.0.1.. solved, tnx.

Comment: This problem also have in blazor web server global 8.0.0. & 8.0.1. after new scaffolded item identity ... . solved, tnx.

Answer (score 3):

For me (ASP.NET Core v2), I had:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
                    .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>()
                    .AddRoleManager<MyRoleManager>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

in Startup.cs. And when I scaffolded Identity, it added IdentityHostingStartup.cs, and I had copy/pasted another similar but default block in based on some email sending code:

```cs
builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
                    {
                        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;//TODO:
                    })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
                });
```

So I moved ALL Identity config into IdentityHostingStartup.cs (ie only 1 configure!!!) it worked as expected...

Answer (score 3):

---

I had the same issue, I was registering services in two different files in the same time: Startup.cs and IdentityHostingStartup.cs files.

### What I did?

I sepeprated registering the services in both files as following:

### IdentityHostingStartup.cs

I only registered Identity DB Context in this file:

```
//lets register identity db context
builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDBConnection"),
        x => x.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplication1")
        )
    );
```

### Startup.cs

In this file I registered DefaultIdentity, Roles and EntityFrameworkstores

```
//I registered the DefaultIdentity, the Roles and the EntityFrameworkstores
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, problem was after add:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

confliting with below code, in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a change from .Net Core 2.0->2.1, I guess the guide hasnt been updated.

After stumbling upon [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744006/asp-net-core-2-1-identityuser-issue-cannot-create-a-dbset-for-identityuser) I :
Removed the lines entire  services.AddIdentity()...call (all 3 lines) (but of course kept the AddDefaultIdentity()-call that was there before

Changed back in ApplicationDbContext.cs from

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```

... So if your starting out from scratch (new .Net Core 2.1-template), all you have to do is add lines

```
     services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
        {
            facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["...FacebookLogin:AppId"];
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["...FacebookLogin:ClientSecret"];
        });
```

from the tutorial.

At least this "fix" takes me through so far that the users can register, havent investigated where my "ApplicationUser" went (in case/when I want to add more user-properties)...since there is no reference to it anymore

Answer (score 0):

if removing the "addDefaultIdentity" from  "Startup.cs" does not work for you .

Replace `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`  to  `AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>`

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmnEc.png)

```
/*
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
*/

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and I had the same issue after I scaffolded a new razor page Login and Register

what I have found is  a new file with the following name created "IdentityHostingStartup"
and has the following code :

```html
public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<IdentityExplorationContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        
 
 
 context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityExplorationContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityExplorationContext>();
            });
        }
```

and the problem here is we have AddDefaultIdentity duplicated in two different files
if you remove the one from the newly created file after the scaffolding step
your app will work fine again

so the function above should be as follows :

```html
public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<IdentityExplorationContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                                               context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityExplorationContextConnection")));

            });
        }
```

this worked for me

hope this helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to use one of these, not 2 or more of them, make sure there is no duplication in your program.cs regarding these :

- AddIdentity
- AddIdentityCore
- AddDefaultIdentity