# System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application: After Identity Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I had an existing `ApplicationUser`, and I wanted to modify the UI page of Login. So this is why I decided to perform the scaffold operation.

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

But when I use the last `CLI` command this :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files="Account.Login;"
```

I can't be able to run my web application, this is what it shows on the web :

[image]

And then, this is the error which occurs in the log :

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already
>   exists: Identity.Application    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String
>   name, Action`1 configureBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.b__0(AuthenticationOptions
>   o)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String
>   name, TOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
>   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name,
>   Func`1 createOptions)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1
>   options, IDictionary`2 schemes)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1
>   options)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
>   singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(RequestDelegate
>   next)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host,
>   CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host,
>   CancellationToken token)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
>   at ICFERApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   /Users/idrislutaaya/RiderProjects/ICFERApp/ICFERApp/Program.cs:line 17

I had a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433112/system-invalidoperationexception-scheme-already-exists-identity-application) but it didn't help me.

Actually what surprises me, there's a DBClass which creates it's self in this directory **~/Areas/Identity/Data**, below :

[image]

```
public class ICFERAppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ICFERAppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ICFERAppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Yet I was having an existing one here :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Students)
                .WithOne(u => u.User);


            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Education)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);


            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(g => g.Guardian)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);

            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Parents)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);

            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Siblings)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);

            builder.Entity<Siblings>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Entity<Siblings>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.StudentId});

            builder.Entity<Education>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Entity<Education>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.StudentId});


            builder.Entity<Guardian>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Entity<Guardian>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.StudentId});
            builder.Entity<Parents>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Entity<Parents>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.StudentId});


        }
    }
```

Then, in my `Startup.cs` file, I followed what the Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) says :

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddTransient<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();
            services.AddMvc().AddNToastNotifyToastr();


            services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
                .UseBinary(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
                    ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary()
                    : jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                .AsUtility()
                .Create());

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowAreas = true;
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
                });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseNToastNotify();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Student}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

With all the information above, what really went wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` and comment out below line if it exits :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ICFERAppIdentityDbContext>();
```

In short only one identity configuration is needed .  [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/8223) is a related discussion .