# Startup.cs class is missing in .NET 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webapi

I created REST API's in .NET 5 and everything was working perfectly, but recently I moved to .NET 6 and realized that no startup.cs class is present. How do I add the DB Context in .NET 6 since there is no startup.cs?

Comment: Have you seen [Minimal APIs overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0)? Besides, not using the minimal API (and Startup.cs for that matter) equally works in .NET 6 if you have existing code.

Comment: See also the migration guidance at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: It is no longer needed. But if you really want to add it back, you may refer to this blog: https://www.strathweb.com/2022/02/using-an-existing-startup-class-with-asp-net-6-minimal-hosting-model/

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In .NET 6 Microsoft has removed the Startup.cs class. Just go to the program.cs file and there you can add a connection string then you have to use `builder.Services.AddDbContext`

The old way is

```
services.AddDbContext
```

Just use `builder.Services` and then you can achieve what you want.

Comment: You can still use a Startup class if you want. You'll just have to use an older template and upgrade or you can make the previous style Program and Startup classes manually.

Comment: the builder resolves by 'var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);' which can later be used to configure the DbConetxt , AutoMapper  etc..
eg : builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt=>opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMem"));


After executing the build (var app = builder.Build();) that resolves to IApplicationBuilder

Later, that 'app' is used to call the RUN / HTTPRedirection etc..

Comment: @asfend Shouldn't you need to mention that it needs to be written in `Program.cs` file instead?

Answer (score 57):

In .NET 6, they unified `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` into one Program.cs.

Now registering middleware, services and adding DbContext and everything else into the Program.cs file.

Here is an example of a Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//Register services here
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(       
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")       
));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(...)
var app = builder.Build();
//app.UseAuthentication();
```

For more information [visit this](https://mobiletonster.com/blog/code/aspnet-core-6-how-to-deal-with-the-missing-startupcs-file) thread.

Answer (score 24):

Create a new class called "Startup.cs". Paste this template in it;

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add serices to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddDbContext...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

    }
}
```

Now, you can Modify your Program.cs class to look like this;

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration); // My custom startup class.

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services); // Add services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app, app.Environment); // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.Run();
```

Now, things are better organized, in the old way. People coming from ASP.NET Core 5 will feel right at home. What you put inside ConfigureServices() and Configure() will depend on your project and needs. For example, here is how an example ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project's Startup.cs would look like as a starting point;

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add serices to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked as charm in the webapi template, by using dotnet new webapi -f net6.0, Thank you :).

Answer (score 8):

To be clear for those trying to add transient, singleton or scoped services...

Previously in **Startup.cs**, adding a service looked like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
}
```

Now instead in **Program.cs**, it looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
```

Comment: Should you do this even if your application isn't a "web application" (not an HTTP microservice) but instead a console job that for example... listens to RabbitMQ or processes a file?

Comment: @BrandonRos Sure you could find dependency injection useful in a console app, for example, configuration data. Look up "when should you use dependency injection".

Comment: @BrandonRos dependancy injection is a design pattern, not something special to web apps. console apps can have a service container too. you can check out DataProtection documentation as an example.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to create an extension class that can be very clean

```
public static class HostingExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add services to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static WebApplication ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        return builder.Build();
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static WebApplication ConfigurePipeline(this WebApplication app)
    {
        
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();
        return app;
    }
}
```

and then just write this to program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.ConfigureServices().ConfigurePipeline().Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **program.cs**, and then you have to use the **builder.Services**

**Here is an example of a Program.cs file:**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```