# Is it good to create Startup.cs in .NET Core Projects rather than registering services in Program.cs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-minimal-apis

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Minimal API project. Why was the `Startup.cs` file removed from newer versions of .NET Core? Is there a specific reason for this change?

Additionally, is the integration of service and middleware registration into the `Program.cs` file, as shown in the provided code snippet, considered the recommended and more intuitive approach for configuring applications in the latest versions of.NET Core?

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).UseDefaultServiceProvider(x => x.ValidateScopes = false).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952271/startup-cs-class-is-missing-in-net-6

Comment: this refers to the registering services, my question is why this startup class been removed   is there any intuition ? @Alex

Comment: If you use it, what's left in Program.cs? Nearly nothing. But if you want, you can still opt-in. After the compiler has chewed it up and spit out IL, it's going to look _very_ similar anyway.

Comment: It was removed because it was boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has dumped the old template with `Startup.cs` file and it is now rather deprecated practice - if you have great registration logic (DI registartion) and configuration (configuring the app from config files, etc.), you could consider separate class with static methods or extension methods on `IServiceCollection` to register you application-wise service and apply your configs.

But new way is to have single startup code located in `Program.cs` which has all. There you get instance of `WebHostBuilder`, on which you can configure DI (`WebHostBuilder.Services`). Using `Build()` method, you get the application object, that will run the ASP.NET app (with `Run()` method). Using the app object you can also register middlewares and endpoints.

Here we come to another improvement in new .NET - minimal APIs, where you can define endpoints directly using the app object, for instance: `app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World");`, so no more need for controllers - again, as long as this code inside endpoints is small and concise, it could be placed there. But in more complex logic I recommend creating separate controller files anyway.

So there it is - there are new ways possible to create your ASP.NET Web API, but as with everything - where to use it and how - **it depends** :)