# Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to all code to get all users with their roles so I had to change up my code a bit and ran into this error. I'm not sure what I did wrong, I narrowed it down to my startup.cs and `ApplicationDBContect` class. I have no errors, and I might need a migration, haven't done that to prevent causing more issues.

I reference [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744006/asp-net-core-2-1-identityuser-issue-cannot-create-a-dbset-for-identityuser) and had other errors.

**ApplicationDBContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Change `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` to `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, ApplicationRole>()` and try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see you are extending both `IdenityUser` and `IdentityRole` with `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` respectively but you did not add them in your identity service registration. So update your identity service registration in startup as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>() // </-- here you have to replace `IdenityUser` and `IdentityRole` with `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` respectively
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: This is the answer that helped me. I had neglected to add the `services.AddIdentity<T>()` to my `Program.cs`/`Startup.cs` file